# Materials cuts out

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I have this image but in the soffa this is something wrong with the material which is looks liks it is cut even if there is no edges and all the sofa back is one piece. I tried to solve it with adding a loop cut but it became worse with stretched material.

[image]

[image]

[image: So sample Standard UV]

[image]

Comment: UV Seams? Check your UV Map and post screenshot of it.

Comment: Hi LukeD, I did posted it.

Comment: Yeah, it's certainly because of UV Map. Did you used Smart UV Map?

Comment: Yes I did but without seems because the texture I used is seemless

Comment: Seamless or not Smart UV Mapping could be suitable for Texture Painting (not always though). If you want texture to look as you want you should place Seams manually and then Unwrap the mesh.

Comment: Do you use any modifiers on the object? Are all faces of the mesh assigned to one material (which uses shown image)? Make sure to check if texture is actually seamless (and there isn't any areas of the color shown in the screenshot). Smart UV Unwrap should be perfectly able to avoid any problems like one shown if the texture is seamless.

Comment: Hi guys, I did like everything I can but no good results!!! I uploaded the blender file so I hope you can take a look into it.

Comment: Why don't you just unwrap the model?

Comment: Apply scale (Object mode > Ctrl+A > Scale). I didn't see any problems if using simple Smart UV Project though but unwrapping with non-uniform scale is bad idea regardless, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7967/1245

Comment: Hello guys! thank u all for ur answers. It works well now after I did apply the scale with the Smart UV Projection. XD